# pass data to $_POST php

Tags: php, post

How can I pass a value/variable to $_POST?
Im not getting all data to my php function. So i just figured out to pass them explicitly.

Can anyone tell me how this is done?

Comment: What is making the POST request to your php file?

Comment: $_POST is regular PHP variable. If you aren't familiar with assigning values to arrays, you'd better refer to manual first: http://php.net/types.array

Comment: @Douglas, a html form is making the POST request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check what's in `$_POST` and then check your HTML form if it's correct.

```
print '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
print '</pre>';
```

Or you can directly assign value to `$_POST` as it's (almost) a normal array:

```
$_POST['test'] = 'hi';
```

But I suppose that's not what you're looking for.

Comment: Thats exactly what i need. But getting it out again is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

the $_POST array is used to retrieve the data that has been sent to your PHP page/script with an HTTP POST request.

Are you asking how to explicitly assign values to $_POST without it being automatically assigned in the request?  If so, why would you want to do this?

Comment: im not sure if i said it correctly. I need to get some data out of POST. But i'm not getting all data. So im wondering how i can explicitly pass data to that POST thing.

Answer (score -1):

If I am reading your question right, you want to pass a value from outside the [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) of the function, to inside it's scope, right?
This usually is unnecessary when using proper code paradigms in PHP, but you can access a global variable from inside a function using the *global* keyword.

The *global* keyword in use:

```
$test = 1;

function funca() {
    global $test,$foo;
    $test = 2;
    $foo = 8;
}

function funcb() {
    global $test,$foo;
    @echo $test."\n";
    @echo $foo."\n";
}

funcb(); // prints 1 and gives error
funca();
funcb(); // prints 2 and 8
```

Comment: $_POST, $_GET and others are superglobal variables, they don't need to be "globalized".

Comment: @dwich Actually, I do not suggest using global on superglobals. What gave you that idea???

What I am saying is that Yustme might be using $_POST in a way that although it works, was never supposed to be used that way, so I suggested a way to do it *without* using any special variables.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, it's about not having all info in $_POST array, possibly caused by incorrectly written HTML form. It's not about how or when to use global or variable scope.

Comment: So you think it might be as simple as adding square brackets after the name of an multiple option field?